# Continuity and image of an open interval

Tags: continuity, monotone-functions

There is a theorem, that a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which maps every open interval to an open interval, is strictly monotonic de/-increasing.

Does this theorem also hold for the other implication, so that for a given strictly monotonic continous function $f$ over an open interval $I$, the image $f(I)$ ist also an open interval?

My guess is yes, having drawn some examples, but actually I can neither prove it nor give a counter-example.

Comment: Have you tried showing that $f\left[(a,b)\right] = (f(a), f(b))$ for $a < b$?

Comment: Hint: consider $c=\inf\{f(x)\colon x\in I\}$ and $d=\sup\{f(x)\colon x\in I\}$; how does $f(I)$ compare to $(c,d)$?

Comment: Do you know that continuous functions map intervals to intervals?

Comment: I know that continuous functions map intervals to intervals.

Well, consider a continuous, strictly monotonic function $f$, let $I$ be an open interval and consider $c: = inf \{f(x): x \in I\}$ and $d: = sup \{f(x): x \in I\}$. For any $a \in f(I)$, the following inequality holds: $f(a) \ge c$. Suppose that $ \exists a' \in I$ with $f(a') = c$. Choose $\epsilon > 0$ so that $(a' - \epsilon) \in I$. Because $f$ is strictly monotonic, we have $f(a' - \epsilon) < f(a) = c$, which is a contradiction to $c$ being the infimum. So $c \notin I$, analog to that $d \notin I$, thus $f(I) = (c,d)$

Comment: What do you think of that proof?

Comment: @X3nius  It is correct. Perhaps you should separately consider the cases $c = -\infty$, $d =  \infty$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yeah that makes sense!